# Oxyplot showing HeatMapSeries behind ScatterSeries

Tags: heatmap, scatter, oxyplot

I am trying to combine LineSeries, ScatterSeries and HeatmapSeries on a single OxyPlot instance. I am able to show the first two just fine on the same plot and it looks like the following:
[image]
The axes for this are generated by the following code:

```
var xAxis = new DateTimeAxis();
xAxis.Key = "X";
xAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
xAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(CurrentPass.AOS);
xAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(CurrentPass.LOS);
xAxis.AxislineColor = xAxis.TextColor = xAxis.TicklineColor = xAxis.MajorGridlineColor = OxyColors.DarkGray;
var yAxis = new LinearAxis();
yAxis.Key = "Y";
yAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
yAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = 0.0;
yAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = MaximumFrequency;
yAxis.Maximum = MaximumFrequency;
yAxis.AxislineColor = yAxis.TextColor = yAxis.TicklineColor = yAxis.MajorGridlineColor = OxyColors.DarkGray;
```

If I add in a third axes for the Heatmap (not even a HeatMapSeries yet), I get the following:
[image]

The extra code here for the axis for the HeatMap is:

```
var heatmapAxis = new LinearColorAxis();
heatmapAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = 0.0;
heatmapAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = MaximumFrequency;
heatmapAxis.Palette = OxyPalettes.Gray(1024);
heatmapAxis.Key = "HeatMap";
```

I am not sure what's going on here. The line series still shows. And all the ScatterPoints from the scatterseries I have are definitely there - the tracker shows up and I can interact with the points (hover, click etc.). But the points don't show. If I add a HeatMapSeries, the HeatMapSeries data does show up as expected, the LineSeries data still shows up but no ScatterSeries data.

Again, the HeatMap data and the Scatter Series data show up individually, but never together.

Has anyone encountered this before? Are there workarounds?

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a bit late but just stumbled upon this. I had something similar with a line not showing up on a Heatmap and after some experimenting i realized the order in which the series' are added to the plot model make a big difference. Make sure you add your ScatterSeries after you've added your Heatmap to the plot model.